# Limit text length to n lines using CSS not working on iOS

Tags: css, ios, overflow, ellipsis

Limiting the text length to n lines using CSS is not working on iOS, is still showing all the lines, here is my code:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
.container {
   height: 2em; /* or whatever height you want to set */
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).